# Divs with percentage width still wrapping when viewport shrinks

Tags: html, css, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/rExDY/

If the result panel is wide enough, the page behaves as I want with the nav on the left and content on the right. What I'd like to happen when the viewport shrinks is to have the content shrink once it hits the nav, rather than wrapping below it. I've been playing around with min-width and can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the content width set to 90%. If the viewport is so small that the `<nav>` box won't fit in the remaining 10% of the width then the content wraps below it. If you reduce the content width to 80% you will see that it behaves much better, but the proper way to write it is to reserve an absolute-width column for the `<nav>` element on the left of the window.

Comment: This gets me closer, thanks. Once it shrinks far enough I'll be using media queries to rearrange things anyway, so this should be good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the table-cell property (IE8 and up only), and add a fallback (eg. with fixed with for `nav`) for IE7 and below:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/rExDY/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try playing around with something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/rExDY/27/

The nav and content will not overlap unless the screen is very small. You could use some CSS3 to shift the nav if it reaches a certain width.